# ASP MVC3 condition falling through unexpectedly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have this condition set up at the top of my ASP MVC3 web page. For whatever reason, however, the program falls through, each and every time, into the `else` statement and labels the page results as being complete. We are testing right now, so there are only two records in the table the model is pulling from, and both have an `I` in the `RecordStatus` field.

I have tested to see if the `Model` object being returned is null, and it is not. I have also tested for the value inside `Model.RecordStatus` and found that it will output an `I`.

If anyone can see something I'm missing it would be *greatly* appreciated. Thanks

EDIT

RecordStatus will always equal either an `I` for `Incomplete` or a `C` for `Complete`. They will always be uppercase.

```
@model Monet.Models.AgentTransmission

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
<div>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <h2>Edit Agent - Record Status:    
    @if (Model.RecordStatus.Equals("I") || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.RecordStatus))
    {
        <span style="color:Red;">Not Saved</span>
    }
    else
    {
        <span style="color:Black;">Complete</span>
    }    
    </h2>
```

Screen shot:

[image]

Comment: So basically if `RecordStatus` is uppercase I, not null and not whitespace you will use the not saved block. Can't really help you without seeing exactly what comes back for RecordStatus, maybe you can include a screenshot of the immediate window.

Comment: Edited - basically yes you will always get back either an `I` or a `C`, both being uppercase.

Comment: What if you output the value to the page to see what it actually is?

Comment: Did that with one of the fields on the form, and it outputs an `I`

Comment: What if you change it to == rather then Equals ?

Comment: Same result. It was written that way to begin with, thought that might have been the problem.

Comment: Make sure there is no space(s) around value "I". Try this: `Model.RecordStatus.Trim().Equals("I")`

Comment: That was it. Do you want to provide that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved, per the suggestion in the comments, by eliminating any potential white space. Below is the syntax:

```
Model.RecordStatus.Trim().Equals("I")
```